# Convert keycode to unicode symbol

Tags: c, unix, sdl

Is there any way to convert keycode to char in C on Unix system? I use SDL lib that send we SDL_KEYDOWN event with pressed scancode & keycode and with zero unicode field. I found solution that request open console, but I can do this only on root user. There is must be another way to convert keycode to unicode symbol on C

Comment: Do you want to use the libsdl for this or is a solution doing raw X calls okay?

Comment: Usually for text entry with SDL, you don't use the scancode, you use "event.text.text". Like in this example code: https://bitbucket.org/cegui/cegui/src/f68564f1404e4b90cf9962a6b513abb1edfcf465/application_templates/SDL2.cpp?at=v0-8&fileviewer=file-view-default#SDL2.cpp-282 Can you explain clearly why you need this? It sounds like an XY problem